# Can code reordering affect my test

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, compiler-optimization

I am writing an unit test for a class to test for insertion when no memory is available. It relies on the fact that `nbElementInserted` is incremented AFTER `insert_edge` has returned.

```
void test()
{
    adjacency_list a(true);

    MemoryVacuum no_memory_after_this_line;

    bool signalReceived = false;
    size_t nbElementInserted = 0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            a.insert_edge( 0, 1, true ); // this should throw
            nbElementInserted++; 
        }
        catch(std::bad_alloc &)
        {
            signalReceived = true;
        }
    }
    while (!signalReceived); // this loop is necessary because the 
                             // memory vacuum only prevents new memory
                             // pages from being mapped. so the first
                             // allocations may succeed.

    CHECK_EQUAL( nbElementInserted, a.nb_edges() );
}
```

Now I am wondering which of the two statement is true:

- Reordering can happen, in which case `nbElementInserted` can be incremented before `insert_edge` throws an exception, and that invalidates my case. Reordering can happen because the visible result for the user is the same if the two lines are permuted.
- Reordering cannot happen because `insert_edge` is a function and all the side effects of the function should be completed before going to the next line. Throwing is a side effect.

*Bonus point*: if the correct answer is “yes reordering can happen”, is a memory barrier between the 2 lines sufficient to fix it?

Comment: The C/C++ specifications require that optimizations all have results that appear "as-if" the optimization didn't happen. However, this is only practical to implement and only required within the regular execution of the program. Operating system signals like POSIX SIGHUP and threads are outside the C++ specification and break the "as-if" assumptions. In your case, even though you call it `signalReceived` it isn't a POSIX signal and won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Reordering only comes into play in multithreaded or multiprocessing scenarios. In a single thread the compiler cannot reorder instructions in a way that would change the behavior of the program. Exceptions are not an exception to this rule.

Reordering becomes visible when two threads read and write to shared state. If thread A makes modifications to shared variables thread B can see those modifications out-of-order, or even not at all if it has the shared state cached. This can be due to optimizations in either thread A or thread B or both.

Thread A will always see its own modifications in-order, though. Each [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) must happen in order, at least as far as the local thread is aware.

Let's say thread A executed this code:

```
a = foo() + bar();
b = baz;
```

Each `;` introduces a sequence point. The compiler is allowed to call either `foo()` or `bar()` first, whichever it likes, since `+` does not introduce a sequence point. If you put printouts you might see `foo()` called first, or you might see `bar()` called first. Either one would be correct. It must call them before it assigns `baz` to `b`, though. If either `foo()` or `bar()` throws an exception `b` *must* retain its existing value.

However, if the compiler knew that `foo()` and `bar()` never throw, and their execution in no way depends on the value of `b`, it could reorder the two statements. It'd be a valid optimization. There would be no way for the thread A to know that statements had been reordered.

Thread B, on the other hand, would know. The problem in multithreaded programming is that sequence points don't apply to other threads. That's where memory barriers come in. Memory barriers are cross-thread sequence points, in a sense.

Comment: I am confused: how does the compiler know in advance whether the code is multithreaded?

Comment: @qdii A different thread could observe out-of-order behavior with respect to how this thread modifies shared state, but this thread will always see its own actions happen in order.